# ObservableCollection and ListView strange behavior under iOS

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, observablecollection

I bind an ObservableCollection called `Messages` to a ListView in Xamarin Forms.
I populate the collection as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    Messages.Insert(0, 
                new Message() {
                   Text = "M"+i
                });
}
```

This works as expected under Android, and my ListView shows 5 messages with texts `'M0',..,'M4'`.
However, under iOS I will get the 5 messages, but each of them shows the text `'M4'`.

When I walk this in the debugger, it shows the correct text for each messages (`'M0',..,'M4'`). So the data is correct, but the ListView shows the text of the last message in each message, rather than the correct text.

Not sure what's happening here.  Any ideas/workarounds?

Thanks!

EDIT:
See my own answer/solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the ListView extension I was using had a custom renderer for iOS which was causing the problem. Once I switched to Xamarin's out-of-the-box ListView, the problem disappeared.

Morale of the story, be careful when using control extensions.

Answer (score 0):

1.Based on your code I wrote an example that will display correctly on iOS for your reference：

Here is the xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="mylist">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Text}"></Label>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the background code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<Message> observableCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Message>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
           
            observableCollection.Insert(0, new Message() {Text = "m" + i });
        }
        mylist.ItemsSource = observableCollection;
    }
}
```

2.According to your code, the index position you insert every time is 0, so the display of the result should be m3, m2, m1, m0.